# How to update data on a page using ajax script?

Tags: ajax

There is a script that needs to update the data on the page in a specific div. But instead of updating, the block with the div is simply hidden and in order for it to appear again, you need to reload the page. The data comes in data, but here is $ ("# userPost" + id) .html (data); something doesn't work.

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    }
});

$('.infinite-scroll').on('click', '#editPostButton', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var id = $(this).data('id');
    var user_id = $('#userForm').val();
    var form = document.getElementById('EditPostForm'+id);
    var formData = new FormData(form);
    // var formData = $('#EditPostForm'+id).serialize();

    $.ajax({
        url: "id"+user_id+"/"+id+"/edit",
        type: "POST",
        data: formData,
        success: function(data) {
            console.log(data);
            $("#userPost"+id).html(data);
            $("#closeButton"+id).click();
        },
        error: function() {
            console.log('error');
        },
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
    });

});
```

And div

```
<div id="userPost{{$post->id}}">
                                        @if($post->img)
                                            <div>
                                                <a href="{{route('userPost', ['id' => $user->id, 'postId' => $post->id])}}" style="text-decoration: none"><img src="{{$post->img}}" class="img-fluid"></a>
                                            </div>
                                        @endif
                                        <br>
                                        @if($post->title)
                                            <div class=" mr-1 mb-3 titleleft">
                                            <a href="{{route('userPost', ['id' => $user->id, 'postId' => $post->id])}}" style="text-decoration: none"><h5 style="color: black"><b>{{$post->title}}</b></h5></a>
                                        </div>
                                        @endif
                                        @if($post->message)
                                            <a href="{{route('userPost', ['id' => $user->id, 'postId' => $post->id])}}" style="text-decoration: none"><div class="text-muted text-small margins" style="white-space: pre-wrap;">{{mb_strimwidth($post->message, 0, 600, " . . . Read more")}}</div></a>
                                        @endif
                                        @if($post->videoPost)
                                            <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9 mt-4 mb-2">
                                                <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src="{{$post->videoPost}}" allowfullscreen></iframe>
                                            </div>
                                        @endif
                                    </div>
```

Comment: hi , where is `#editPostButton` in your code ? Also does `id` have correct value or not ?

Comment: #editPostButton This button is in the modal window. When you click on the edit button, this window opens

Comment: but with ajax that doesn't work you mean to say ? did you try opening modal under ajax success ?

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this way:

```
 $("#userPost"+id).load(url);
```

or

```
$("#userPost"+id).html(data).load(url);
```